# Django command makemessages does not generate string marked for translations for files in templates directory

Tags: django, internationalization

I have project in Django==2.2.12

and this is part of my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
            ],
        },
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = "pl"

TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Warsaw"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

LANGUAGES = (
    ('pl', gettext('Polish')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

When I execute:

django-admin makemessages --locale=en

It generates .po files with string to translate in locale directory from .py files but it completly skips .txt files that are located in my templates directory. For example it does not generate string for translation for my text.txt file with following content:

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% blocktranslate %}
string to translate
{% endblocktranslate %}
```

Comment: Does your txt file includes `trans` tag?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to use `{%trans 'your string %}`
2. Use this command to update `.po` files: `python manage.py makemessages -l ar --no-wrap --no-location`
3. Remove `#fuzzy` if it's above what you want to translate
4. Run `python manage.py compilemessages`

I hope this helps!